# Adding anchor tags to first record for each group

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I'm trying to setup a Twitter Bootstrap nav-list (similar to what they use on their own site: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html).

My page grabs everything from "table" and groups the results by "col_a".  I want to be able to add an anchor link to the first record returned for each group.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY col_a, col_b";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    <tr class="<?php echo $tr_owned_class ?>">
        <td><?php echo $row['col_a'] ?></td>
...
```

This ultimately returns something like this (grp_x is returned from col_a):

- row 1: grp_1, data, data...
- row 2: grp_1, data, data...
- row 3: grp_1, data, data...
- row 4: grp_2, data, data...
- row 5: grp_2, data, data...
- row 6: grp_3, data, data...

So, in this example, I'd want an anchor tag on rows 1, 4, and 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the group into a variable the first time it's encountered - something like this:

```
$last_group = '';
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
   $group = $row['col_a'];
   if ($group != $last_group) {
      echo '<td><a href="[url here]">'.$group.'</a></td>';
      $last_group = $group;
   } else {
      echo '<td>'.$group.'</td>';
   }
}
```